# Using SARIMAX for daily data with yearly seasonal pattern

Tags: time-series, python, seasonality, statsmodels

The data consists of a time series with daily frequency. It is basically temperature data, and I can see a clear seasonal pattern throughout the year.

I would like to model this time series using statsmodels SARIMAX method. Since I have daily data and a yearly seasonal pattern, I chose s=365 in the seasonal order parameter. Now my understanding of the other seasonality parameters is as follows: In (P,D,Q,s) I first determined s as before. Then, since s is positive, I chose P=1 and Q=0. My time series is stationary, so I chose D=0.
This leads to the following code:

```
order = (3,0,1)
seasonal_order = (1,1,0,365)

model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
    endog=NG_train,
    exog=HDD_train,
    order=order,
    seasonal_order=seasonal_order,
    time_varying_regression=True,
    mle_regression=False,
    measurement_error=True,
)
```

Now this causes two problems: First of all, the method takes way too long to calculate, and I don't get any results. Second of all, if I would get results I suspect my model would be heavily overfitted, as to my understanding this adds 364 extra parameters to it. I am struggling with the method's documentation, hence why I am asking my question here. Is there any way to overcome this problem? I would be happy to include monthly seasonality, however simply setting s=12 doesn't work, and I don't want to aggregate my data to monthly data.

Comment: Do not use SARIMA(X) with very long seasonal periods: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/
Use Fourier terms or other alternatives instead.

Comment: @RichardHardy: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, this is a duplicate, so there is no point in answering it. But I did not have the time to look for the relevant thread to close this one against, so I just posted a comment...

Comment: @RichardHardy: I did look and did not find anything I could close this as a duplicate of. [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barima%5D%5Bseasonality%5D+long) does turn up a number of "near duplicates".

Comment: @StephanKolassa I haven't come across this question before either. At least not with Python.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you for your response. From the website you linked I read that one shouldn't use SARIMA with long seasonals in R. I did not find anything that said the same about Python, should I just assume that that's the case as well? Furthermore, do I understand it correctly if for one seasonal I should put K=1 in the formula on the website, and add the trigonometric part as an exogenous regressor?

Comment: @user21551428, the problem with long seasonal periods for SARIMA is more fundamental than a specific implementation such as R or Python. It will pop up regardless of what software you use.